# How do you get Eclipse/Mylyn to fill out your commit messages for you?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I've setup the following:

- Installed Mylyn in Eclipse
- Installed the Bugzilla connector
- Installed Subversive SVN Integration for the Mylyn Project
- I've gone to Windows -> Preferences -> Tasks -> Team and clicked Change Set Management and left it with the default Commit Comment Template:
   `${task.status} - ${connector.task.prefix} ${task.key}: ${task.description} 
  ${task.url}`

However, if I activate a bugzilla bug in the Task List, and then edit a file, when I commit the changes the commit message isn't filled in.

Also, in the Synchronisation perspective there isn't a change set for the task I'm working on.

I've tried following the instructions on the Eclipse wiki's Mylyn FAQ for [Why does task change set not appear when I modify files?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn_FAQ#Why_does_task_change_set_not_appear_when_I_modify_files.3F) but the bullet point:

- Verify that the [configured Synchronize View is configured for change sets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/User_Guide#Configuring_the_Synchronize_view_for_change_sets). points to a section that is no longer in the document.

I have a Show Change Sets button, but clicking it only shows me incoming change sets, there aren't any outgoing change sets.

What am I missing?

Comment: I suggest to post a link to this question on the [Mylyn newsgroup](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/support/). That should give you a quick answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=170128&start=0&

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you activate the checkbox "**Automatically create and manage with task context**" in the group "Change Set Management" in the preference page?

I had a quick look at the Eclipsepedia article for Mylyn and you havent mentioned the **Mylyn-Bridge** in your installation. Did you install this feature?. 
The article also says that you also need enabling features for the Client you are using

I am on Eclipse 3.4 with Mylyn 3.3.2 and this works just fine. There is probably something missing in your configuration.

Here is what is installed on my system (with the standard CVS-Client):

- Mylyn Bridge: Eclipse IDE
- Mylyn Bridge: Java Development
- Mylyn Bridge: Team Support
- Mylyn Connector: Bugzilla
- Mylyn Task List
- Mylyn Task-Focused Interface

If you are using Subversive **you also need the Subversive Team Provider** and similar it goes for Subclipse.

Comment: Thanks, it was the Subversive Team Provider I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was using the task focused changesets as in here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/User_Guide#Task-focused_Change_Sets

Answer (score 0):

I had to install **Subversive SVN Integration for the Mylyn Project** from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/2.0/update-site/

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue even though the properties were set correctly and I had all connector installed.
To fix issue, it was necessary to:

1. disable the checkbox **"Automatically create and manage with task context** under MyLyn/Team preferences,
2. Apply modifies
3. Recheck the box.
   After applying of these modifies, automatic message re-appeared to my comments